# Using credentials from Db2 (Warehouse) on Cloud to initialize flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, ssl, db2, ibm-cloud, flask-sqlalchemy

In a Flask app with [flask-sqlalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/), I am trying to initialize a connection to Db2 Warehouse on Cloud by setting **SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI** to one of the parts provided in the service credentials. In the past, going with the **uri** component worked fine, but my new service has SSL connections only.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=dbInfo['uri']
```

This results in connection errors

> File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_db_dbi.py", line 592, in connect
>   conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, '', '', conn_options)
>   Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "52.117.199.197".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "104", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001 SQLCODE=-30081 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

It seems that the driver is not accepting the `ssl=true` option specified in the URI string. What parts of the service credentials should I use? Would I need to build the URI string manually?

Comment: [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74180001/13155046)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a partial answer because of a workaround. I am using the port information from the service credentials to modify the connection URI:

```
if dbInfo['port']==50001:
    # if we are on the SSL port, add additional parameter for the driver
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=dbInfo['uri']+"Security=SSL;"
else:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=dbInfo['uri']
```

By adding `Security=SSL` to the **uri**, the driver picks up the info on SSL and uses the correct settings to connect to Db2.